# Is there a way to save the values of a 2D array into multiple 1D arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am trying to read a .txt file and save it into an array called path[6][11] (no issues here). Then I want to split the 2D character array, by row, into 1D arrays and save it into arrays called path_#[when i = 0 save the j=0 to j=11 character values] (# being the row it represents). Is it possible to use a for loop to save the values row by row of a 2D array into 1D arrays and if so could you show me a line of code to be able to do this?

These are the characters being saved into the 2D array.

```
X X X X X B X X X X X
X X X F X F X F X X X
X X E X S X F X G X X
X S C G X C X S S X X
F X G E X E E F G G X
X X X X G F R X X X X
```

the hope is that i can make it into

```
path1 = {X X X X X B X X X X X}
path2 = {X X X F X F X F X X X}
```

and so on...

for further clarification here is my code:

```
#include iostream

#include string

#include fstream

int main() {

    int n = 6, m = 11, i, j, q, t;

    char path[6][11];

    // Sets place holder values to the arrays to avoid using uninitialized arrays

    char StartZone[6] = { 'a' }, path1[6] = { 'a' }, path2[6] = { 'a' }, path3[6] = { 'a' }, path4[6] = { 'a' }, path5[6] = { 'a' };

    std::ifstream Map("map.txt"); // opens map file and saves to object "Map"

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { //first for loop cicles through the rows of the txt file Map
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) { // second for loop cicles through the columns of the txt file Map
            Map >> path[i][j]; // saves the contents of map into a 2D array called path
            std::cout << path[i][j] << " "; //prints the map
        }
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl; // for extra spacing so the map prints clearly
    }

    Map.close();
    
This is where I am having the issue I try to use a for loop although I'm unsure how I would set it up for this task. I've writen out what I hope to happen.

    if (i == 0) { //if i in path[i][j] == 0 (first row) then take the j values from 0 to 11 and save it into startzone. at least thats the hope
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            StartZone[j] = path[j]; // where only the values of the columns j are saved into the startzone 1D array
        }
    }
```

Comment: A 2D array _is_ multiple 1D arrays all joined together.

Comment: A 2D array is nothing else than an array of arrays. Therefore, your question does not make sense. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Ok, this is what you're trying to do. However you forgot to mention the most important part of any question that gets posted to Stackoverflow: a question. What is your question? Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted.

Comment: What difficulty did you face trying to do this? The straight-forward, naive approach works, doesn't it? Tough for us to guess where you went astray without seeing your work. *There's also the question of why you would want to...*

Comment: Why do you want to have your characters stored in arrays named `path_0` to `path_5`? What is wrong with `path[0]` to `path[5]`? The latter seems better, as it is more flexible. For example you can easily loop over all arrays using only the identifier `path`, instead of having to handle 6 different identifiers.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel wouldn't that just store the value of the 1st and 6th cell of the 2D array?  the goal with the 6 arrays is to have them each hold the values of their respective row in the 2d array so that i can manipulate them later in my code.

Comment: @jaMiT Is the naïve approach to just separately save each row into its own array manually? I wanted to see if there was a way to do this with a for loop instead. when looking through similar questions to mine, the closest thing i found to saving a 2D array into 1D arrays was by taking every value in the 2D and making it into a single 1D. I figure if that's possible making a 2D array save its values into 1D arrays equaling its row count is possible as well.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik is my question Clearer now?

Comment: @paddy do you know how to separate it BACK into 1D arrays using a loop of some kind? i just want to know if its possible without having to manually set each array to the values in map.txt

Comment: What is even the point?  Why are you copying the arrays to begin with?  If you're just wanting some variable to reference part of the 2D array, use pointers: `char *StartZone = path[0], *path1 = path[1], *path2 = path[2], .... ;`  There seems to be some fundamental misunderstanding on your side, and it's not translating into questions that make sense to experienced developers.

Comment: No, I'm afraid that it's still unclear exactly what your question is. Can you please indicate which sentence in what you wrote above is actually asking a specific question? All I read above is some vague, generic problem statement, followed by some code, and ...that's it. The End. No question. ***What is your question***?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I hope that made it clearer. I've added the question to the end of the first paragraph then added even more clarification to the code portion of the question.

Comment: @josuenugget *"I wanted to see if there was a way to do this with a for loop instead. "* -- that might be what you meant to ask, but it is not what you (had) actually asked. You had asked if it was possible. End of question. Now you've added "to use a for loop", which is an improvement. However, you your question still contains a false statement: *"I don't know how to approach this."*

Comment: @josuenugget *" wouldn't that just store the value of the 1st and 6th cell of the 2D array?"* (I know, directed at someone else) -- A single subscript does not give a cell of a **2**D array; it takes **2** subscripts. The 1st cell of the 2D array is `path[0][0]`, and the 6th is `path[0][5]`. The type of `path[0]` (only one subscript) is `char path[11]` (remove the innermost subscript). The type of `path[5]` is also `char path[11]`, and the 11 values in this array are those from the sixth row of your 2D array. Hence the question why you want to go through the trouble of copying values.

Comment: @JaMiT so i tried to print out the row using path[0] but that just prints the array as one line starting at the row you specify aka 0 or the first row in this case. at this point im just going to hard code the values i was just hoping to challenge myself and make it in a for loop but it seems theres no point.

Comment: @josuenugget *"but that just prints the array as one line starting at the row you specify aka 0 or the first row in this case."* -- which is exactly what you asked for. You asked for `path1` to be `X X X X X B X X X X X` a.k.a. the first row in this case.

Comment: @JaMiT if you read what i said, it prints the ENTIRE 2D array starting at the indicated row. again, when i did path1 = path[0] printed out  X X X X X B X X X X X X X X F X F X F X X X X X E X S X F X G X X X S C G X C X S S X X F X G E X E E F G G X X X X X G F R X X X X.

Comment: @josuenugget: If an attempt to print `path[0]` causes more than that sub-array to be printed, then the problem is not the 2D array, but rather how you are attempting to print the sub-array. If you simply did `std::cout << path[0];`, then this is wrong, because using `operator <<` like this requires the argument to be a pointer to a null-terminated string. However, `path[0]` is not null-terminated. Therefore, you should use `std::cout.write( path[0], sizeof path[0] );`  instead. Your question is an example of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @josuenugget *"prints the ENTIRE 2D array"* vs. *"prints the array "* -- not the same thing at all. In the context *"print out the row using path[0] but that just prints the array"*, the closest antecedent for "the array" is the 1D array "path[0]", and that connection is reinforced by calling the result "one line". Debugging requires precision; ambiguity is counter-productive. It would have been less ambiguous to use a name, as in "just prints the rest of `path` starting at the specified row".

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Since a 2D array is nothing else than an array of arrays, it does not make sense to "split" a 2D array into its individual 1D arrays.

## Solution to the X problem

In the comments section, you stated that when you attempt to print `path[0]`, it prints the entire array `path`, instead of only the sub-array `path[0]`. I assume that this is happening because you are not printing it properly.

In your question, you do not show how you are attempting to print `path[0]`. However, I suspect that you are attempting to print it as a null-terminated string, for example like this:

```
std::cout << path[0];
```

This will not work, because `path[0]` is not null-terminated. If you want to print a sequence of characters that is not null-terminated, you can print it like this:

```
std::cout.write( path[0], sizeof path[0] );
```

## Solution to the Y problem

Although this is not the solution to your actual problem, I will give you a direct answer to your question anyway:

> Is it possible to use a for loop to save the values row by row of a 2D array into 1D arrays and if so could you show me a line of code to be able to do this?

Yes, it is:

```
#include <iostream>

#define ARRAY_LENGTH 11

int main()
{
    char path[6][ARRAY_LENGTH] = {
        { 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'B', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X' },
        { 'X', 'X', 'X', 'F', 'X', 'F', 'X', 'F', 'X', 'X', 'X' },
        { 'X', 'X', 'E', 'X', 'S', 'X', 'F', 'X', 'G', 'X', 'X' },
        { 'X', 'S', 'C', 'G', 'X', 'C', 'X', 'S', 'S', 'X', 'X' },
        { 'F', 'X', 'G', 'E', 'X', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'X' },
        { 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'G', 'F', 'R', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X' }
    };

    //declare 6 1D arrays
    char path_0[ARRAY_LENGTH];
    char path_1[ARRAY_LENGTH];
    char path_2[ARRAY_LENGTH];
    char path_3[ARRAY_LENGTH];
    char path_4[ARRAY_LENGTH];
    char path_5[ARRAY_LENGTH];

    //create array which refers to all 1D arrays, so that they
    //can be used in a loop.
    char * const arrays[] = { path_0, path_1, path_2, path_3, path_4, path_5 };

    //copy data from 2D array `path` to the 1D arrays path_0 to path_5
    for ( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
        for ( int j = 0; j < ARRAY_LENGTH; j++ )
            arrays[i][j] = path[i][j];
    
    //print the individual 1D arrays
    std::cout.write( path_0, sizeof path_0 ) << '\n';
    std::cout.write( path_1, sizeof path_1 ) << '\n';
    std::cout.write( path_2, sizeof path_2 ) << '\n';
    std::cout.write( path_3, sizeof path_3 ) << '\n';
    std::cout.write( path_4, sizeof path_4 ) << '\n';
    std::cout.write( path_5, sizeof path_5 ) << '\n';
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
XXXXXBXXXXX
XXXFXFXFXXX
XXEXSXFXGXX
XSCGXCXSSXX
FXGEXEEFGGX
XXXXGFRXXXX
```

As you can see, all sub-arrays of the 2D array were successfully copied to the individual 1D arrays `path_0` to `path_5`.

However, it would have been much simpler to print `path[0]` to `path[5]` directly:

```
#include <iostream>

#define ARRAY_LENGTH 11

int main()
{
    char path[6][ARRAY_LENGTH] = {
        { 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'B', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X' },
        { 'X', 'X', 'X', 'F', 'X', 'F', 'X', 'F', 'X', 'X', 'X' },
        { 'X', 'X', 'E', 'X', 'S', 'X', 'F', 'X', 'G', 'X', 'X' },
        { 'X', 'S', 'C', 'G', 'X', 'C', 'X', 'S', 'S', 'X', 'X' },
        { 'F', 'X', 'G', 'E', 'X', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'X' },
        { 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'G', 'F', 'R', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X' }
    };

    for ( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
        std::cout.write( path[i], sizeof path[i] ) << '\n';
}
```

The output of this program is the same as that of the other program.